# Windows 8.1 clock time always wrong

Tags: 13.10, windows-8, time, clock

I am using dual boot operating systems on my Dell Inspiron N4050 laptop with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 13.10. The time in Windows remains correct while I keep using it. But when I log into Ubuntu and then again restart my laptop and login to Windows, my Windows clock always shows the wrong time, a difference of about 5 hours. I have configured my region and synchronized it to the time at windows.com, but I am still facing the same problem. Please give me guidance.

Comment: Correct the time in Windows and then log in to Ubuntu. Does Ubuntu show correct time then?

Comment: Yeah. Time of Ubuntu remains correct.

Comment: Is five hours your UTC offset? Linux likes the clock to be UTC and windows likes the clock to be in local time

Answer (score 0):

You might do well to change the internet time settings (there should be a tab on your clock settings) to use a different internet time source. The one from microsoft.com seems to be the one that somehow screws up if your system clock time is UTC.

Not sure how all of that works, but I changed it to nitc.gov or some such and it works fine.